# is mysqladmin status locking?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I'm having lag issues with master slave replication with a mysql server.
        `Server version: 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)`
I'm running a cron that uses `$ mysqladmin status` every minute.
Is this query using locks of any kind?

thanks!

Comment: Why you would think so ? May be the O/P is going std err ?

Comment: I'm getting the result of the query.
the questions is whether this query is using any kind of locks on the db or the tables